# magento 2 custom css in custom theme not being applied

Tags: magento-2.1

I am having a problem with my custom theme in magento 2, for some reason the css I'm writing isn't showing up on the site.

I have created my custom theme at

```
app/design/frontend/Matt/New/
```

it's parent is the blank theme and I am able to apply the theme with no errors. I have created a less file at

```
web/css/source/style.less
```

the contents of the file is

```
#maincontent{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I can run "grunt exec:New" and that works without any errors. I can then deploy with no errors. If I then restart xampp and reload the site the style is not applied. I have checked the source by pressing "ctrl +  u" and I can see that the style.less file is there under

```
<link  href="http://test.dev/pub/static/version1484246990/frontend/Matt/New/en_GB/css/source/style.less" />
```

The styles are not in the either of the files styles-m.css or styles-l.css though. I have tried clearing cache, deleting pub/static. I'm not sure what else to do or what the problem could be, does anyone have any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding there are only two files that get automatically picked up and pulled into the styles-m.css and styles-l.css files from your theme:

`_extend.less`

and

`_theme.less`

The `_theme.less` file will override the same file in the parent theme, were as the `_extend.less` will just be added onto the other files. Try changing that and see if your styles show up.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. I don't know how I didn't noticed that in the documentation!

Comment: sweet, glad it worked!